# What’s is a good title when writing about my hobbies interests and beliefs

Tags: grammar

I’m having troubles with coming up with a title and topic sentence for my hobbies interests and beliefs

Comment: The Diary of a Narcissist.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is asks for "writing or naming advice or critique requests".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to check the main idea of all you are going to write about.

For example, you are going to write about your hobbies,interests, and beliefs so it could be:

**My hobbies** or **My favorite things to do** or **My personality**

(I personally think **My personality** is best)

The topic sentence is the main idea for each paragraph.

The paragraph for hobbies topic sentence: **I have many hobbies** or **I do alot of interesting things in my spare time**.

The paragraph for interests topic sentence: **The things I find interesting are ____** or **My interests are also fascinating**.

The paragraph for beliefs topic sentence: **I believe that _____** or **My strongest belief is ____**.

The concluding sentence sums up the topic sentence of the paragraph.

Hope this helps

Comment: Please check at the Help Center regarding what topics are considered appropriate/inappropriate. Suggestions for names or titles, helping improve style (general writing advice), proofreading ... are off-topic.